# I can't iterate over object Object

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I got nested JSON like this

```
{"id":1,"category":"cat","iconUrl":"www.test.com","subCategoryEntity":[{"id":3,"subCategory":"sub3","products":[]},{"id":2,"subCategory":"sub2","products":[]},{"id":1,"subCategory":"sub1","products":[{"id":1,"fileDownloadUri":"http://localhost:8081/api/v1/downloadFile/paint-bucket-orange-2-300x300.jpg","productName":"Name","productPrice":20.0,"productDesc":"this is the discreption","productStock":15,"productImages":[]}]}]}
```

[image]

I need to iterate over all sub categories and get all the products in sub category

here is my Angular code

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of allProducts| keyvalue">
       {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
   </div>
```

and this is the output
[image: i can't access this object object]

Comment: your subCategoryEntity is an object, that's why you cannot iterate it like the previous properties

Comment: Is there is away to access the elements in sub category ? it shown in browser console If not is this API needs to refactor again ?

Comment: can you add what's your expectation value here and how it should be represent you value?

Comment: the expected value that i can print the the sub categories and all products in sub categories .

Comment: i was thinking about using interface but i don't know if this work

Answer (score -1):

To iterate in all products inside all the subcategories you can do the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let subCategory of allProducts.subCategoryEntity">
   <div *ngFor="let product of subCategory.products">
      {{product.id}}-{{product.productName}}
   </div>   
</div>
```

I think this is what you want, its not the best way to do this.

I recommend you to iterate over the 'allProducts' and the 'subCategories' and extract the products in a variable to do only one 'ngFor'

Comment: Doesn't work i got an error the cannot iterate over the object only iterate over array

Comment: The object 'allProducts' is an array?

Comment: I got this error  Property 'subCategoryEntity' does not exist on type '{}

Comment: @JoséEduardoUrzedaFerreira the first line of his question contains the object. You should have read it completely

Comment: @Alaaebeed that`s weird, because in the object of your question has the 'subCategoryEntity', please show us the 'allProducts' object in typescript